# Invariant Violation: ReactShallowRenderer render()

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs

I am writing a unitTest script for the following reactjs file.

```
export default class Collapsible extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        title: React.PropTypes.string,
        children: React.PropTypes.any,
    };

    render() {
        const { title } = this.props;
        return (
            <details>
                <summary>{title}</summary>
                {this.props.children}
            </details>
        );
    }
}
```

Following the uniTest Example Here ,  i though i could do like below.

```
import React from 'react'
import expect from 'expect'
import {createRenderer} from 'react-addons-test-utils'
import {Collapsible } from '../Collapsible.js'

describe('Collapsible', ()=>{
    it('works', ()=>{
        let renderer = createRenderer();
        renderer.render(<details><summary>Title</summary>Text</details>);
        let actualElement = renderer.getRenderOutput();
        let expectedElement = (<details><summary></summary></details>);
        expect(actualElement).toEqual(expectedElement);                     
    });
});
```

However, when i run my test , i get the error

> Invariant Violation: ReactShallowRenderer render(): Shallow rendering
>   works only with custom components, not primitives (details). Instead
>   of calling `.render(el)` and inspecting the rendered output, look at
>   `el.props` directly instead.

Please where do i go wrong ? How do i write the unitTest for the script above. ?Any help would appreciated.

**Update**

```
import React from 'react'
import expect from 'expect'
import {createRenderer} from 'react-addons-test-utils'
import {Collapsible } from '../Collapsible.js'

describe('Collapsible', ()=>{
    it('works', ()=>{
        let renderer = createRenderer();
        renderer.render(<Collapsible title="MyTitle"><span>HEllo</span></Collapsible>);
        let actualElement = renderer.getRenderOutput();
        let expectedElement = (<details><summary></summary></details>);
        expect(actualElement).toEqual(expectedElement);                     
    });
});
```

When i run the code above, i get

> Cannot read property 'propTypes' of undefined  . I am guessing may be i have to pass the title and props.children considering they are properties in Collapsible. Please how do do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using your `Collapsible` element in your test, which is why you're getting that error.

The error message that you get you'll get using any primitive element, that is basically any HTML tag, you can only pass your own components to the Shallow renderer.

```
renderer.render(<Collapsible />);
```

Comment: Anderson thanks for the reply , your point makes sense . However, now i am having an error `Cannot read property 'propTypes' of undefined` . I am guessing its because my {title} and my                 `{this.props.children}` from Collapsible has not been set . Please how do i pass those properties in your answer above ?

Comment: Can you paste the code that you're trying to run. I've just copy/pasted your code above and it works OOTB.

Comment: @Anderson, Please excuse my questions i am quite new to this. Please i have update my question based on your answer. Please why does throw the error above ?.